# Send out 10,000 messages within 1 minute

Tags: php, mysql, apple-push-notifications

Platform: Linux

Engine: php-apns

I have 10,000 messages need to send out in 1 minute. I separate it out to 4 cron jobs every minute to blast them out, each cron job sends 1,000 messages, 300 messages per each connection to APNS server. The last message sent out took more than 15 minutes. Hence the user received my alert message 15 minutes late.

Any idea how to send out all messages within 1 minute?

Comment: Without any code, the best advice is: get a better server.

Comment: You need more `scripts that send messages` (from [php-apns docs](http://php-apns.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README)), i.e., more cron jobs.

Comment: i am asking for idea/concept of sending out 10,000 messages within 1 minute ... is it possible ? if yes, how ? what i can think is multi-tasking by using cront job.

Comment: Are you asking how to program a spam-server :-?

Comment: Hi Johan, APNS stand for Apple Push Notification Service. I am not doing a spam server !!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would recomend a CDN for this. Have several servers programmed to communicate with each other, and send out all your messages.